# how to extract text from a tag which has no specific tag?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have a html code from which I have to extract a text. if it was in href tag I could use get_attribute("text"), however in this weird code, there is no tag.

```
<h2 class="slideable title">
<span content-slot="title" transcluded="49763">Black Diamond Cheese Bars 400-450 g</span>
</h2>
```

I want to have Black Diamond Cheese Bars 400-450 g

i tried to get element with name content-slot but I am unable to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using `soup.span.text`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mahesh, I am using selenium find element instead of BS

Comment: Its unclear what the problem is. You can't locate the element? you can't extract the text? something else?

Comment: Hey, thanks I could do it with x path

Answer (score 0):

use the parent class selector then access the child using .(dot) operator using **BeautifulSoup**

```
html.find('div',{'class':'slideable title'}).span.get_text()
```

Comment: Thanks for comment @ashishkumar148, I am using selenium find element instead of BS

Comment: you have added bs tag so i thought you to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use `getText()` method to acheive this, `getAttribute()` returns attribute value

Try this

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@transcluded='49763']"));
String s=ele.getText();
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

Black Diamond Cheese Bars 400-450 g

Comment: Thanks for the reply sankalp, Yeah I could have done it, but in my case I have many transcluded names with different id's. I can't use it to get everything

Comment: In that case use xpath of that element or use that ID to locate span, or use if-else to check it. Glad it helps you Please accept as answer on clicking on right

Comment: finally it worked with xpath but I had to play around with the format as im doin this in python..thank you

Comment: Glad, it works. Please accept and upvote if it helps you

Comment: did it, but i dont have enough credits to see the actual upvote